# How to limit number of words per line to a fixed width?

Tags: javascript, css

Hi guys I am trying to figure out how to limit the amount of words generated per line via javascript. These words are used with the span tag, so each word is separate and the words come from an array and are just iterated out. I want to have it stop printing words when two lines are full. Suggestions?

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="wordsBox">
        <span wordnum="1" class> Test </span>
        <span wordnum="2" class> Test </span>
        <span wordnum="3" class> Test </span>
        </div>
</div>
```

container is 960px, so I want to figure out how to stop generating spans once two lines fill up.

Answer (score 0):

First determine your character width in px. If this isn't a static number, create a div with a single character in it, then grab the dimensions of that div (be sure to remove it's padding, borders, outline, etc).

```
var charWidth = 12;
var maxLines = 2;
var containerWidth = 960;
var wordArray = ["Test","Test"]; //To whatever length....
var maxLength = Math.floor((containerWidth*maxLines)/charWidth);
var currentLength = 0;
while(currentLength < maxLength) {
  currentLength = document.querySelector("#wordsBox").innerText.length;
  var nextWord = wordArray.shift();
  if(nextWord.length + currentLength < maxLength) {
    document.querySelector("#wordsBox").innerHTML += "<span ..>"+nextWord+"</span>";
  } else {
    currentLength = maxLength;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't quite work, trying to figure it out...the second line doesn't get created. It does limit the first line though which is good

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. It's exactly your code. Here is a quick fiddle with it, http://jsfiddle.net/sq5nb4qh/

Comment: Check this one out. Remember, setting a font to "36px" doesn't mean the width is 36px a piece. You need to get the math accurate. Also, be sure to use a monospace font. I've set that here: http://jsfiddle.net/sq5nb4qh/3/